# Facing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/shaded/guava18/com/google/common/escape/Escapers

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Facing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/shaded/guava18/com/google/common/escape/Escapers on building Flink Job jar with Flink 1.13. I have seen Flink 1.13 using 18.0 version of Google guava and I am using Hadoop version 2.8.3

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-shaded-guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0-${flink.shaded.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Detail logs

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/shaded/guava18/com/google/common/escape/Escapers
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.clusterframework.BootstrapTools.<clinit>(BootstrapTools.java:75)
        at org.apache.flink.yarn.entrypoint.YarnEntrypointUtils.loadConfiguration(YarnEntrypointUtils.java:83)
        at org.apache.flink.yarn.entrypoint.YarnJobClusterEntrypoint.main(YarnJobClusterEntrypoint.java:94)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.shaded.guava18.com.google.common.escape.Escapers
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 3 more
```